# bramqp & node.js : Error on cancelling consumer (basic.cancel)

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, cancellation, consumer

Firstly, I'm new to rabbitmq and bramqp. I know this might be a stupid question but I've been pulling my hair out because of this problem in cancelling consumer from a queue. I've searched through the whole internet and found no bramqp example of how to do basic.cancel code.

Here is my code :

```
        var bramqp = require('bramqp');
        var net = require('net');
        var async = require('async');

        var queueName = 'testQueue';
        var consumerTag = 'testConsumer';
        var exchangeName = 'testExchange';

        var socket = net.connect({
            port : 5672
        });

        bramqp.initialize(socket, 'rabbitmq/full/amqp0-9-1.stripped.extended', function(error, handle){
            async.series([ function(seriesCallback) {
                handle.openAMQPCommunication('guest', 'guest', true, seriesCallback);
            }, function(seriesCallback) {
                handle.exchange.declare(
                    1 /*short reserved-1*/,
                    exchangeName /*exchange-name exchange*/,
                    'fanout' /*shortstr type*/,
                    false /*bit passive*/,
                    true /*bit durable*/,
                    false /*bit auto-delete*/,
                    false /*bit internal*/,
                    false /*no-wait no-wait*/,
                    {} /*table arguments*/
                );
                handle.once('exchange.declare-ok', function(channel, method, data) {
                    console.log('exchange declared');
                    seriesCallback();
                });
            }, function(seriesCallback) {
                handle.basic.qos(
                    1 /*long prefetch-size*/,
                    0 /*short prefetch-count*/,
                    1 /*...*/,
                    false /*bit global*/
                );
                handle.once('basic.qos-ok', function(channel, method, data) {
                    console.log('qos accepted');
                    seriesCallback();
                });
            }, function(seriesCallback) {
                handle.queue.declare(
                    1 /*short reserved-1*/,
                    queueName /*queue-name queue*/,
                    false /*bit passive*/,
                    true /*bit durable*/,
                    false /*bit exclusive*/,
                    false /*bit auto-delete*/,
                    false /*no-wait no-wait*/,
                    {} /*table arguments*/
                );
                handle.once('queue.declare-ok', function(channel, method, data) {
                    console.log('queue declared');
                    seriesCallback();
                });
            }, function(seriesCallback) {
                handle.queue.bind(
                    1 /*short reserved-1*/,
                    queueName /*exchange-name destination*/,
                    exchangeName /*exchange-name source*/,
                    null /*shortstr routing-key*/,
                    false /*no-wait no-wait*/,
                    {} /*table arguments*/
                );
                handle.once('queue.bind-ok', function(channel, method, data) {
                    console.log('queue bound sucessfully');
                    seriesCallback();
                });
            }, function(seriesCallback) {
                handle.basic.consume(1 /*short reserved-1*/,
                    queueName /*queue-name queue*/,
                    consumerTag,
                    false /*no-local no-local*/,
                    false /*no-ack no-ack*/,
                    false /*bit exclusive*/,
                    false /*no-wait no-wait*/,
                    {} /*table arguments*/
                );
                handle.once('basic.consume-ok', function (channel, method, data) {
                    console.log('consuming from queue');
                    console.log(data);
                    handle.on('basic.deliver', function (channel, method, data) {
                        console.log('incoming message');
                        console.log(data);
                        handle.once('content', function (channel, className, properties, content) {
                            console.log('got a message:');
                            console.log(content.toString());
                            if (content.toString().indexOf("END_MESSAGE") > -1){
                                handle.basic.cancel(consumerTag, false);
                                handle.once('basic.cancel-ok', function(channel, method, data) {
                                    console.log("consumer cancelled successfully");
                                    seriesCallback();
                                });
                                res.json("END_MESSAGE");

                            }
                            else{
                                console.log('acking');
                                handle.basic.ack(1, data['delivery-tag']);
                            }
                            console.log('with properties:');
                            console.log(properties);
                            seriesCallback();
                        });
                    });
                });
            } ], function() {
                console.log('all done');
            });
        });
```

So, what I'm trying to do is just simply stopping the consumer when it detects a message with 'END_MESSAGE' type. What I get from the code above is the following error:

```
    events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
    TypeError: value is out of bounds
        at TypeError (<anonymous>)
        at checkInt (buffer.js:705:11)
        at Buffer.writeUInt16BE (buffer.js:730:5)
    req.on('error', function(e){
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
```

Any advice and suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Somehow I solved the problem by omitting all the parameters inside basic.cancel().

So, just with handle.basic.cancel() is enough for life!

Maybe someone could explain why does it work without any consumer tag specified? Could it be that rabbitmq can automatically detect the consumer tag?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the basic.cancel() works a little bit different, at least today. I found in the documentation that this method actually eats a callback, like this:

```
handle.basic.cancel(consumerTag, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bramqp-wrapper - search for basic.cancel

**IMPORTANT!** The callback does NOT guarantee you do not get any more messages from the queue. It seems it is fired simply for accepting the cancellation, not when it is actually digested by the queue server.